# How do I take data from user using char* and then performs deep copy of entered data in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

[Take data from user in runtime from char*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEWy.png)

Comment: code should be included as text (with code formatting) in the question. Please do not use images or links to external sites for code.

Comment: the quesiton is unclear. `char*` is a pointer to `char`. To store user input you need a string, use `std::string` (or a raw array of `char`s if you really want to)

Comment: Your problems are not in the copying but in pretty much everything else.

Comment: Something wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: Also don't spam unrelated tags. The `C++17` and `c++14`  tags are pointless here. Your question is about C++, period.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `std::string`, which performs all the data lifetime management and deep copy for you.

In turn, that makes the `Student` class's destructor, default constructor, copy constructor all just *do the right thing*.  Also the assignment operator will just *do the right thing*, but that's not exercised in the `main` routine.

In the code, I used `= default` on the destructor, default constructor, and copy constructor to highlight that the default compiler generated routines are good.

A couple of improvements would be for `Getinfo()` to be `Getinfo(istream& in, ostream& out)`, and for `show()` to be `show(ostream& out)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::runtime_error;
using std::stof;
using std::stoi;
using std::string;

static auto get_string(istream&) -> string;
static auto get_int(istream&) -> int;
static auto get_float(istream&) -> float;

class Student final {
    string name;
    int age = 0;
    float gpa = 0.0f;
public:
    ~Student() = default;
    Student() = default;
    Student(string n, int a, float g) : name{move(n)}, age(a), gpa(g) { }
    Student(Student const&) = default;

    void Getinfo() {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        name = get_string(cin);
        cout << "Enter your age: ";
        age = get_int(cin);
        cout << "Enter your GPA: ";
        gpa = get_float(cin);
    }

    void show() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << "\n"
            << "Age: " << age << "\n"
            << "GPA: " << gpa << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Student s1;
    s1.Getinfo();
    s1.show();
    Student s2 = s1;
    s2.show();
    Student s3(s2);
    s3.show();
}

auto get_string(istream& in) -> string {
    string line;

    if (getline(in, line)) {
        return line;
    }

    throw runtime_error("get_string");
}

auto get_int(istream& in) -> int {
    string line;

    if (getline(in, line)) {
        return stoi(line);
    }

    throw runtime_error("get_int");
}

auto get_float(istream& in) -> float {
    string line;

    if (getline(in, line)) {
        return stof(line);
    }

    throw runtime_error("get_float");
}
```